# Write data on google sheets through android app form

Tags: android, google-sheets-api

I am new to android and I want to publish my form data which is created in an android app to google sheets. Can anyone help me out with this problem

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://codesmith.in/post-data-google-drive-sheet-through-mobile-app/ detailed step by step guide with image screen shot.

Comment: i have already gone through this example, this is done with the help of google forms, and i don't want to use google forms.

Answer (score 0):

This is totally doable. Checkout the [Android Quickstart for Sheetsv4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/android) to give you an idea of the code flow. Then the main thing you have to know is to [Write on A Single/Multiple Range](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#writing_to_a_single_range) using

```
PUT https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheet_id/values/range?
            valueInputOption=value_input_option
```

You can find actual writing sample in [Basic Writing](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/writing):

```
 https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheetId/values/Sheet1!A1:D5?valueInputOption=USER_ENTERED
```

Comment: I have used the above api but it throws an error "name must not be null"